# How to fill a 2 dimensional array from a list of strings

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

My program is supposed to read a file that looks like this:

```
8 7
~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~
B~~~~~~
~~~~~~~
~~~~B~~
~~~~B~~
~~~~~~B
~~~~~~~
```

I need to disregard the first line (8 and 7) and read the following characters into a 2-D array. I thought the code I wrote up would do so, but it doesnt. I need map[0][0] to correspond to the first "~", and for map[3][0] to correspond to the first 'B'. This is the code I'm using.

```
try 
    {
    File file = new File(args[1]);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);     
    String themap = sc.nextLine();
    theFirst = themap.indexOf(" ");
    theSecond = themap.lastIndexOf(" ");
    int rows = Integer.parseInt(themap.substring(0, theFirst));
    int columns = Integer.parseInt(themap.substring(theSecond+1)); 
    char[][] map = new char[rows][columns];  

    while (k < rows)                                
        {   
        //System.out.println(k);
        while (j < columns)
            {
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) 
                {
                themap = sc.nextLine();                                        
                System.out.println(themap);
                map[k][j] = themap.charAt(j);
                System.out.println(map[k][j]);
                }

            j++;
            }
        k++;
        }
        sc.close();
    } 
catch (Exception e) 
    {
    System.out.println("ERROR: File does not exist");
    }
```

I threw in a test statement there to see what was happening with map[j][k] and it only prints out the first character of each line. Like I said, I need it to correspond to the file I'm reading it from, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you should disregard the first row, you should read in 8 (number of rows) and 7 (number of columns) and use those to determine how much you should be reading from the following rows.

Comment: I think I may have phrased that poorly. I'm not disregarding it completely since I'm using it to get the int values of rows and columns, but they aren't going to be read into the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are reading *every line* due to the inner `while` loop every *column* (not 1 line every *row*).

Move the `nextLine()` call outside the column loop.

Other improvements:

- It seems obvious that the first line is the number or rows and columns - you should rely on and use that
- Don't use `while` loops, use `for` loops and name the loop variable `row` and `column` to make your code more readable
- Don't use `hasNextLine()` as a loop control - check it if you must and throw an exception if a line should be there but isn't
- make your code more modular by creating a method to return an array of char given a String
- consider throwing an exception if the line length is incorrect
- use `nextInt()` to read the numbers

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `nextLine()` repeatedly within your innermost loop on the first time through; after which there's nothing more to read.  So the only thing you're populating is `map[0][0]`.

You need to get rid of the innermost `while` loop entirely, and move `sc.nextLine()` to inside your outer loop.

The basic structure should be this.  Feel free to add any `println` calls and error checking.  Also, many people would find it more intuitive to use `for` loops instead of `while`.

```
while (k < rows) {   
    themap = sc.nextLine();                                        
    j = 0;
    while (j < columns) {
        map[k][j] = themap.charAt(j);
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your looping is incorrect . try this.
Your logic to determine no of rows and columns is good and there is no problem with that. Some people have mentioned that you discarded the first line but you didn't.

```
    for(int i=0;i<rows&&sc.hasNextLine();i++){
        themap = sc.nextLine();
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
            map[i][j] = themap.charAt(j);
            System.out.print(map[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```